# Simular ajax sincronos en un bucle

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Ya sabemos que ajax es asincrono y la única forma de hacerlo síncrono es poniendo la opción `async: false`.

lo que quiero hacer es algo así

```
for (var fact in facturas ) {
    sendEmailAJAX(facturas[fact]);
    console.log(fact+ "enviado!!!");
}
```

Quiero que vaya llamando a `sendEmailAJAX` de una en una y no todas a la vez.

Lo puedo hacer con `async:false` pero el navegador se bloquea.

No se me ocurre como darle solución a este problema.

Comment: Tal y como está, las llama **de una en una**. Lo que quieres es que **espere a que una termine antes de llamar a otra**, ¿ no ?

Comment: Si, busco que se ejecute `sendEmailAJAX` una después de otra, de tal forma que en el log se mostrarían las facturas enviadas en orden

Comment: En ese caso, para hacerlo bien, lo que hay que modificar es la propia función `sendEmailAJAX( )`. O usando un temporizador, como te han indicado en la respuesta, pero eso **no te da garatías** de que termine haciendo lo que quieres.

Comment: "el navegador se bloquea" señal de que posiblemente es una mala idea hacerlo asi y podrias pensar en otra forma. Si aceptas otras ideas, edita tu pregunta aclarandolo y explicando que es lo que estas trantando de hacer.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

podrias establecer un tiempo para que se vuelva a ejecutar el codigo que esta en tu `for`, algo asi:

```
for (var fact in facturas ) {    
    setInterval(function(){
        sendEmailAJAX(facturas[fact]);
        console.log(fact+ "enviado!!!");
    }, 5000);
}
```

donde 5000 especifica 5 segundos de espera para enviar el siguiente y lo puedes modificar a tu gusto dependiendo el tiempo q se use para cada operación.

**UPDATE 1**

```
for (var fact in facturas ) {
    $.when(sendMailJs(fact)).done(continue);
}
function sendMailJs(){
    sendEmailAJAX(fact);
    console.log(fact+ "enviado!!!");
    return true;
}
```

para mas informacion consulta la documentacion de $.when() en la pagina oficial de jquery

Comment: He sopesado esa solución pero las peticiones no siempre tardan lo mismo.A las malas tendré que utilizarla aunque no sea la óptima

Comment: @Takyo si ya encontraste la respuesta, porfavor añadela como respuesta atu propia pregunta y deleccionala como la solucion, o porfavor selecciona la respuesta que te ayudo a solucionar tu problema